# Start only specific beans in ejb

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans

This is Java EE 6, I need some key beans from the EJB dependency, which is huge. It has a lot of `@Startup` beans, a lot of `@Schedule` annotations in there which I don't need to be started in my ear. How it could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

All the session beans / CDI beans in JavaEE are lazily initialized by default. Hence unless a bean is accessed, it won't be started. 
`@Startup` annotation is for `@Singleton` session beans to initialize them eagerly.

During startup, the container scans for all the `@Schedule` annotations, as such all the timers are created at startup. But the beans which contain the `@Schedule` method is only initialized the first time the timer is fired.

Comment: So, how to prevent @schedule from start in a module? Or just start only specific ones.

Comment: It can't be prevented.